# Azure Table Storage & Dynamic TableServiceEntity

Tags: azure-storage

I am looking for a way to create objects in the Azure Table Storage that are essentially dynamic in nature. In other words they have no defined class structure of exposed properties, except for the base ones required by TableServiceEntity.  In other words, like a JSON object.  Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: If you're using the REST API directly you get this for free, you just have to build the xml payload yourself.  Are you trying to access table storage through the .Net storage client library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just had a property on the table called 'Value', which I used to store a JSON string. It works very well, as long as you don't want to use it in a query.

**Edit**

I have created a small library for using dynamic types (or dictionaries) with table storage. Available here (see DynamicTableContext): https://github.com/richorama/AzureSugar

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to achieve so in .Net code, may I suggest you take a look at the source code for Azure Storage Explorer on CodePlex (http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/). I think the name of the class is GenericEntity.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an open source client that allows exactly that.

The Table Storage service is schema free but the provided .NET client does not expose it, it doesn't even mimic the REST API making very difficult to follow the existing API documentation.

With [Cyan](http://cyannet.codeplex.com/) I am trying to provide a less "leaky abstraction" (hi Joel!) of the service using .NET 4 dynamic features.

It's still a work in progress, but you can use some of the code if you want.

Answer (score -2):

I have written an client that supports dynamic (unspecified) columns by using a dictionary to hold the name/value pairs. It also supports many other features like arrays, enums and data larger than 64K.

You can download Lucifure Stash, from http://www.lucifure.com via NuGet.

Comment: Dude you write the most weird c# code I've ever read, any particular reason for this coding style? I will love to know the benefits of it

Comment: I agree the formatting is weird :). Do you find the code constructs weird too? 

I want a consistent formatting style which supports complex expressions and does not take long lines requiring horizontal scrolling.

I avoid using variables unless they really are variable value holders and needs to be used more than once; so I tend to inject code directly as function parameter values.

Ultimately I find that extra white space, column alignment, indenting and link breaks makes it easy for me to distinguish, sub expressions in more complex expressions easily and grasp the code structure better.

Comment: @Lucifer thanks for the explanation, I spend some more time going through the examples and I think I can get used to it, you make some valid points.